# Overloading operators in classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

example:

```
class GameObjectList {
    #list;

    constructor() {

        /** @member {GameObject[]} */
        this.#list = [];
    }

    /**
     *  @param {GameObject} object
     *  @returns {boolean} true if added
     */
    push(object) {    
        if( !(object instanceof GameObject) )
            return false;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.#list.length; ++i) {
            if (this.#list[i] == object)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        this.#list.push(object);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there any way operator `[]` executed on `GameObjectList` would return nth object of `#list`?

```
let list= new GameObjectList();
let objA = new GameObject();
let objB = new GameObject();
let objC = new GameObject();

list.push(objA);
list.push(objB);
list.push(objC);

list[1] // returns objB
```

Or if it is impossible what is best practise to replace it?

Comment: Yes it's possible but it's not an operator that they are overloading it's the property access hook. You can do this using a proxy. JavaScript does not support operator overloading of any sort.

Comment: @AluanHaddad sounds dirty. I think it wouldn't be best practices. Maybe doing custom list is not good idea?

Comment: I I agree that it is not a very good in this situation, but proxies have their uses. They are a hammer though and they're extremely powerful and need to be used carefully

Comment: That said, it's a very subjective question. I wouldn't use the class in the first place myself so the the whole discussion about weather syntax merits the use of some very powerful mechanism is particularly subjective.

Comment: In this particular case you can extend `Array` but it is not a well-accepted good practice too

Comment: @AluanHaddad why not to use class? Class seems to be quite elegant solution.

Comment: I agree with @Shlang. However, if your primary goal is to create an array that only holds instances of a specific class I would advise against even trying

Comment: @AluanHaddad I was Java developer for many years so i have some habits. Maybe I subconsciously try to smuggling some practices for my past years. Why it is wrong idea?

Comment: That's exactly why I don't like classes. They give people the wrong impression and subvert their intuitions if they are familiar with almost any other language. For example, they still don't provide encapsulation. Private fields are still in the process of being standardized and until they are, classes don't provide encapsulation. More broadly, classes tend to cause people to misunderstand the language and use it poorly

Comment: @AluanHaddad What about `#` prefix? Isn't it encapsulation?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean when I say private Fields, but are actually still in standardization. But the language has supported hard privacy and encapsulation for decades. Eventually classes will catch up but they don't offer anything new and they've caused a lot of confusion

Comment: @PiotrZych Even in Java, you'd just use a `List<GameObject>` and not implement your own `GameObjectList` class.

Comment: @Bergi Java is strong typed language. We are sure what we add to list. In other case we cause compilation error. I have to be sure, that each element of list has for example update function to not crash main loop. Of course i can check in main loop if method exists but for me it is obfuscation of the code by redundant error catching. Role of main loop is not study of each object.

Comment: @PiotrZych Then add only objects with an `update` method to your `Array` or `Set` in JS as well. Yes, in JS you can never be sure whether someone has messed with your objects, but that just means you need to write cleaner code and follow conventions. If you want a type checker to complain, use TypeScript instead. And btw, your main loop will have to deal with obects whose `.update()` throws an exception anyway, so it can also deal with objects where that call leads to a "missing method" exception.

Comment: @Bergi In my opinion it is better to force order on design level then dealing with hours of debugging.

I spent a lot of time in the past debugging (not my code), why strange objects appeared in arrays and then causes problems. I dont trust myself, so how I can trust someone foreign?

Comment: If you want to do some kind of type check when adding an object to your list, provide a function for that which hides the list. Write a `class Game { #objectList = []; addObject(o) { … } mainloop(…) { … } }`, but don't try to wrap the array inside a list-like `GameObjectList`.

Comment: @Bergi But still you can do some strange things inside Game object. I can also imagine that if you want to pass objectList as argument to for example collider or any other place then it is susceptible to random modification. If somebody who will write random plugin and would take objectList, will be able to crash the game. I'am glad that JS desingers noticed that problem and implemented classes and encapsulation.

Comment: Having classes is not the same as having static typing. Classes were not added to provide static typing.